Switched branch without commiting changes, 'error: Could not write index. FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/manifest.json: needs merge'
I'm making my edits on a branch while my partner is working on the main. I switched branch to check on their latest push but I didn't commit my change before changing to the main branch. I didn't know it was gonna mess things up for me when I returned to mine. Now I'm stuck with this:
GitHub page:

When I hit restore:


error: Could not write index
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/manifest.json: needs merge
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/packages-lock.json: needs merge
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

I can see that my changes are still there, but how do I restore it?
I've only tried hitting restore and ran into the above error. I directly edited everything from my latest commit. Was told my burst package was removed when I went back to my in-progress-file so I ended up CLOSING it--not sure if I should have. Now I can no longer open the file.
I also selected "leave changes in my branch" before changing to main, and when switching back to my branch I selected "bring change over". But the changes I see stashed so far are accurate to the changes I make.
I don't know how to proceed. I'm afraid of damaging things further. Do I try committing whatever there is to commit - then restore to stash?
I am new to game development, coding, and GitHub, so please have patience with me.

The easiest and safest way to deal with any course control issue like this is to copy your local files to a new directory, then wipe the version controlled working copy (ie your local stuff), check out fresh and then then copy your changes over the top as if you'd just edited them.
Over the years I have found this works to solve any and every issue with your SCM.

Hi! Does this mean going to github web and redownloading the zipfile and using that to replace my current project? Thereafter - hitting restore stash?
Should I close github when I do that?

just copy your files off so they cannot be overwritten, then start again.

I'm really sorry  wdym by copy off - I'm interpreting this as creating a back-up so my older file cannot be overwritten - but using a redownload to start again.
I'm not sure if this is what you mean

Time you should talk to your partner about this. But yes, copy the files to a different folder. Then delete and redownload from git, then copy back.

Aha, we're both fresh to this :') just as lost as I am. We are terrified of pushing and pulling on github - horrified we'd mess smt up. Only just discovered branches this week.

Hi! I did the replacement - but am still getting this problem so can't restore the stashes :')
error: could not write index
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/manifest.json: needs merge
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/packages-lock.json: needs merge
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

Oh bless, I just had to commit the change before restoring, thank you so much!

How on earth has noone already posted the mandatory xkcd? I know it's irrelevant as a comment, but the parallel is just too perfect. No, this is not the way to go. Learn to use git properly.

The following takes up the answer of user gbjbaanb, all thanks go to that answer. Here is how it works:

Delete the damaged file that no longer opens.
Redownload the latest commit you were working on.
Put the healthy file in your project. There is no need to restart or close GitHub, it auto recognizes the new file.

You may get the following error:

error: Could not write index
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/manifest.json: needs merge
FullHarvest_Daph (MajorPush-1)/Packages/packages-lock.json: needs merge
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.


Commit the new file that you've put in your project. That will fix merging.
Restore Changes.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I work with TortoiseGit on Windows. I ran into this error when I tried to "stash apply" some work.
The error says that a file "needs merge", for three files in a row. Therefore I right-clicked the stash entry in the stash list and merged it to my branch. I let it auto-generate the merge message and clicked OK, but the merge failed:

error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (328 ms @ 05.07.2024
16:54:44)

Another pop up showed:

TortoiseGit
While merging, i.e. integrating changes of another (remote) branch into your local branch, a conflict in at least one file occurred. This means that you need to resolve this manually (i.e., you need to integrate your changes into a file which was also modified on another branch).
After resolving all files, you need to perform a commit in order to complete the merge.
If you want to abort the merge, do a hard reset on HEAD or select abort merge on the context menu.
See help for more information.

After clicking OK, three conflicting files were listed, just those that also hindered the "stash apply". With an OK again, I could click:

on "Resolve" on the bottom left
or on "Commit" on the middle right.

I clicked on "Resolve", and the three files turned from red to black, with a blue "Success" below them and the remark on the bottom left (with this grammar):

You need commit your change after resolve conflict

Thus, I could and perhaps should also click on "Commit", but I did not do that since I did not want to have another commit on top.
In the Git tree, I could see that my last commit's work was left untouched. What came up from the failed merge and the "Resolve" were some new work on top of the last commit, three new files that had nothing to do with the files that hindered the stash apply.
I read from this that the conflicts were gone. After this, I could work further. I am not saying that you should just do it the same way, I could just risk this since I knew that I had a copy of my work anyway. I guess that clicking on "Resolve" without picking the right fix should not be done like this. But for me, it worked well, no work on top, I could stash and then hard reset and therefore avoid another commit.
